# is_NA() in Rcpp when combined with all()

Tags: r, rcpp

Does anyone can tell me why the following codes return TRUE. It confuses me.

```
> require(Rcpp)
Loading required package: Rcpp
Warning message:
package ‘Rcpp’ was built under R version 3.3.3 
> src12 <- '
+ #include <Rcpp.h>
+ using namespace Rcpp;
+ 
+ // [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]
+ 
+ // [[Rcpp::export]]
+ bool is_naFUN() {
+ 
+ LogicalVector y = {TRUE,FALSE};
+ bool x = is_na(all(y == NA_LOGICAL));
+ 
+ return x;
+ }
+ '
> sourceCpp(code = src12)
> is_naFUN()
[1] TRUE
```

Acturaly, it comes here. I'm learning the tutorial.
[rcppforeveryone-functions-related-to-logical-values](https://teuder.github.io/rcpp4everyone_en/210_rcpp_functions.html#functions-related-to-logical-values)
how to make a clear understanding about of NA_LOGICAL in Rcpp? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`some_bool == NA` is always returning `NA`, in R or Rcpp, because you don't know what's behind the input, so you don't know the output.

Yet, R is clever enough to know that `NA || TRUE` is `TRUE`, for example.

Answer (score 3):

The present status quo is unintentionally causing missing values to propagate through all checks as `NA` values are "contagious" since there a special data type. This runtime error is in large part due to the order of the comparison being incorrect.

In particular, instead of doing:

```
is_na(all(y == NA_LOGICAL))
```

The order should be:

```
all(is_na(y))
```

In essence, you want to first test to see if the values are `NA` and, then, check to see if all values are `TRUE`.

One last note on using `all()`, there is a special template that requires the end result to be accessed by a member function so that it can be coerce to a `bool`. Thus, we need to add either `.is_true()` or `.is_false()`. See the [unofficial Rcpp API](https://github.com/coatless/rcpp-api/blob/master/rcpp-api-docs.Rmd) section on missing values for more information.

## Fixed Code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool is_na_corrected() {

  LogicalVector y = {TRUE,FALSE};
  bool x = all(is_na(y)).is_true();

  return x;
}


/***R
is_na_corrected()
*/
```

## Result

```
is_na_corrected()
# [1] FALSE
```